# How to to find coordinates of the center of a triangle in a $3$-d environment if the $x, y, z$ vertexes are known?

Tags: geometry, triangles, barycentric-coordinates, triangle-centres

Data provided:

$x, y, z$ coordinates for 3 points in space (it's 3 stars in the solar system).

I have the stars coordinates from the Galactic coordinates system and basically I want to find the $x,y,z$ coordinates for the system at the center of aforementioned triangle.

In short is it possible to find the center of a triangle which is neither parallel to x or y or z plane?

Thanks in advance I apologize for my poor English and whoever will solve me this will make me real happy

Galactic coordinates where sol are $(0,0,0).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_coordinate_system

Comment: Add respective coordinates and divide by 3. --- (Also, there is only *one* star in the solar system)

Comment: Galactic coordinates are not xyz coordinates, but if you have converted to those then the comment from @HagenvonEitzen solves your problem.

Comment: That's center as in average, not center as in minimum equidistant. Not sure which one poster wants.  Although minimum equidistant may not even be in the convex hull of the 3 points.

Comment: Hi thank you for your quick replies. Basically I have three systems, which are Sol (o,o,o) Polaris (-323,+195,-212) and Sagittarius A(-25,-21,25900). I did find the coordinates by doing all the X's divided three and so on. Is that correct ? I mean my triangle isn't parallel to any of the axes xyz shouldn't be more complicated maths for it ?